# python - open, seek, write to a file, from another file

Tags: python, file, seek

I guess I am doing something wrong.
I am not sure what it is though, but I keep getting `TypeError: expected a character buffer object`

I just want to open a file, seek to certain offsets and overwrite data from patch1 and patch2.

Here is the code I am using, please help me and show me what I am doing wrong:

```
patch1 = open("patch1", "r");
patch2 = open("patch2", "r");
main = open("patchthis.bin", "w");

main.seek(0xC0010);
main.write(patch1);
main.seek(0x7C0010);
main.write(patch1);
main.seek(0x40000);
main.write(patch2);
main.close();
```

I am noob when it comes to file handling with python, even though I have read up about it.
I really want to start learning more, but I need some good examples and any help sure would be appreciated :)

Comment: this is PYTHON you don't need the semi-colons

Comment: There's no need to add a semicolon at the end of each line. As long as you only have one statement per line (and you really shouldn't do otherwise), semicolons are unnecessary and redundant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to write file object into file, not a string.
try:

```
patch1_text = patch1.read()
main.write(patch1_text)
```

and so on.

Also use with statement when operating on files:

```
with open('patch1', 'r') as patch1:
    patch1_text = patch1.read()
    patch1.close()
```

And don't use semi-colons at the end of line !!!

Comment: i still am not getting the desired results :( i can write to a file but for some reason i cannot open a file set the cursor to 0xc0010 and write patch1. i know its prob easy but i just can wrap my head around writing to offsets :0

Comment: I can't help you if you wont give more detailed information. What error you get?

Comment: you were correct m8, i apologize for not giving you credit. i was doing what you said about trying to write a string when i really wanted to write a file. i have figured it out after all. thanks for your help m8 :)